# SVG to CANVAS with vector graphics

Tags: canvas, svg, vector-graphics

Hi I'm trying to use [professorcloud](http://www.professorcloud.com/svg-to-canvas/) to convert a svg logo to a HTML 5 canvas.

My problem is that the canvas result does not behave like a vector graphics picture anymore.

Do you know some tool able to do this?

The demo is in `http://jsfiddle.net/Txzrw/`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvas is not a vector device, it's a rasterizer and operates on pixels only. If you want to continue operating on vectors, you should store them separately and redraw logo on canvas every time you change source image.